# How to get back the image from Tensor in libtorch?

Tags: c++, opencv, libtorch

I am trying to get the image back from the tensor I created earlier and visualize it, However, the resulting image is distorted/garbage it seems.
This is how I convert a `CV_8UC3` into the corresponding `at::Tensor`:

```cpp
at::Tensor tensor_image = torch::from_blob(img.data, { img.rows, img.cols, 3 }, at::kByte);
```

and this is how I convert it back to the image :

```cpp
auto ToCvImage(at::Tensor tensor)
{
    int width = tensor.sizes()[0];
    int height = tensor.sizes()[1];
    try
    {
        cv::Mat output_mat(cv::Size{ height, width }, CV_8UC3, tensor.data_ptr<int>());
        return output_mat.clone();
    }
    catch (const c10::Error& e)
    {
        std::cout << "an error has occured : " << e.msg() << std::endl;
    }
    return cv::Mat(height, width, CV_8UC3);
}
```

This is how the original image looks like :

[image]

and this is what I get after conversion :

[image]

Now if I use `at::kInt` instead of `kByte` during the creation of the tensor :

```cpp
at::Tensor tensor_image = torch::from_blob(img.data, { img.rows, img.cols, 3 }, at::kByte);
```

I no longer get the distorted image! however, the network output will be off which means something has gone wrong in the input!

What's the issue here and how should I be going about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the tensor was created using a `c10::kByte` for the cast we need to use `uchar` and not `char` or `uint`, etc . so in order to get this fixed I only had to use `uchar` instead of `int`:

```cpp
auto ToCvImage(at::Tensor tensor)
{
    int width = tensor.sizes()[0];
    int height = tensor.sizes()[1];
    try
    {
        cv::Mat output_mat(cv::Size{ height, width }, CV_8UC3, tensor.data_ptr<uchar>());
        return output_mat.clone();
    }
    catch (const c10::Error& e)
    {
        std::cout << "an error has occured : " << e.msg() << std::endl;
    }
    return cv::Mat(height, width, CV_8UC3);
}
```

Side note :
In case you created your Tensor with any other type, make sure to use `Tensor::totype()` effectively and convert to the proper type before hand.
That is before I feed this tensor to my network, e.g I convert it to `KFloat`
and then carry on! its an obvious point that may very well be neglected and cost you hours of debugging!